# Formatting a barcode with hyphens in between - Assignment question

Tags: c

The assignment at my first year uni computing course says my program should read a barcode number, and then display the same 13 digit barcode number separated by hyphens. For example, 9300675016902 should look like 930-067501-690-1.

The restrictions say I can't use the following:

No arrays
No strings
No functions.

Any directions on this?

So far I have:

```
part1 = barcode/10000000000;
```

which gives me the first three digits, and this:

```
part4 = barcode%10;
```

which gives me the last digit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are on the right track...keep dividing....by the appropriate units....

Comment: You should clarify the restrictions. Without functions, you can't actually output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    long p1 = n/10000000000;
    long p2 = n%100000000000/10000;
    long p3 = n%10000/10;
    long p4 = n%10;
    printf("%03ld-%06ld-%03ld-%01ld\n",p1,p2,p3,p4);
```

Comment: Hmm, that uses strings though.  Taking his assignment literally, he should probably convert to ASCII by adding 48 to each individual digit.

Comment: Better yet, he should convert to ASCII by using '0' instead of 48.  For some of us, the ASCII table is easier remembered in hex rather than decimal (0x30 == '0' == 48).

Answer (score 0):

If you actually can't use strings, you're going to need to do is to go through each digit in turn and use `putchar('0' + x);` where `x` is the current digit..

Answer (score -2):

I'll give you a clue, without answering your homework directly.

Bit masks.

Comment: How do you suggest to extract DECIMAL digits using bit masks?

Comment: Barcodes are read as ASCII text, therefore available in a string. One byte per character.
If the barcode has already been converted into a number then that is a different matter.